# SaveAsPDF Word addin in to C# MSI Installer package

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation, windows-installer

I am developing an C# windows form tool used by our external users, I have a requirement where I need to convert word to pdf, using Saveaspdf word addin and got the code working fine.

( dev environment : VS2010, Word 2010, .Net 4.0 )

I am wondering if users has Word 2010 they dont need to worry about savepdf addin. If they have word 2007 installed, is there any way i can check addin is availabe in the system and launch this addin installation before main application deployment starts?

In simple, I am looking for how can package "Saveaspdf" addin in deployment package.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to find out what version of Word the user has on their system? You can use C# Word automation to find this out.

```
//Start Word and create a new document.
Word._Application oWord = new Word.Application();
string buildVersion = oWord.Build;
// inspect buildVersion to see which version of Word they have
```

There is some more information on Word automation [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316384), but you shouldn't need much more than what I have above. You'll just need to make sure you have a reference to the Microsoft Word Object Library.  HTH

Comment: i have to find word has "Saveaspdf" addin installed, if not i have to install the addin..